# How to the text down line when passing off the div tag

Tags: html, css

[image: Text down line]

How to the text down line when passing off the div tag, Tks so much...

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your container class

```css
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Tks so much <3 it's worked